# How to get more than one NSArray object in NSString using for loop and send that object one by one?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsstring

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to get more the one array in this loop

```
for (NSString *strDevice in Array1) {
        NSLog(@"Print Your Data = %@",strDevice);
        //Send this strDevice to server in loop one by one.
    }
```

This loop only convert one array in string and I am not able to access the string outside this loop.
I have 9 array

```
Array1 = [devices valueForKey:@"key1"];
Array2 = [devices valueForKey:@"key2"];
Array3 = [devices valueForKey:@"key3"];
Array4 = [devices valueForKey:@"key4"];
Array5 = [devices valueForKey:@"key5"];
Array6 = [devices valueForKey:@"key6"];
Array7 = [devices valueForKey:@"key7"];
Array8 = [devices valueForKey:@"key8"];
Array9 = [devices valueForKey:@"key9"];
```

and I need to convert all the array into 9 different string using this loop is it possible?? How can I convert 9 different array in 9 different string.

Note - devices is `NSMutableArray` from core data and it type is `NSString`.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What type is `devices` and what type(s) contains it?

Comment: @vadian It is NSMutableArray.Its data is from core data.

Comment: Please add a concrete example what one of the lines returns and what the expected result is.

Comment: @vadian I want to send array element one by one in string format.

Comment: Why don't you try nested loops? It doesn't seem so hard. Try once and then ask for help.

Comment: @NikhilManapure It Print first string value so many time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `devices` comes from Core Data it cannot contain `NSString`. Either it's `NSManagedObject` or `NSDictionary`. I guess it's `NSManagedObject`.

In this case it's more suitable to use the `NSManagedObject` as object in the loop and get the values for the nine keys respectively:

```
for (NSManagedObject *object in devices) {

    NSSString *string1 = [object valueForKey:@"key1"];
    NSSString *string2 = [object valueForKey:@"key2"];
    NSSString *string3 = [object valueForKey:@"key3"];
    NSSString *string4 = [object valueForKey:@"key4"];
    NSSString *string5 = [object valueForKey:@"key5"];
    NSSString *string6 = [object valueForKey:@"key6"];
    NSSString *string7 = [object valueForKey:@"key7"];
    NSSString *string8 = [object valueForKey:@"key8"];
    NSSString *string9 = [object valueForKey:@"key9"];
    // use the strings
}
```

An alternative is to use an array of `NSDictionary` from Core Data rather than `NSManagedObject`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need this(atleast from your question)-

```
// Preparation
NSArray *array1 = @[@"one", @"two"];
NSArray *array2 = @[@"three", @"four"];
NSArray *devices = @[array1,array2];

// Real work
for (NSArray *array in devices) {
    for (NSString *strDevice in array) {
        NSLog(@"Print Your Data = %@",strDevice);
        //Send to ur server or do anything you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Tell me if you wanted this way only or not. If you explain your problem more elaborately then we can help you more.